# How to filter lists in a list in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm having issues with filtering out lists from a list.

Given a list of lists, I want it to return a list that contains a certain word in the third element.

For example: if I want to find a list of sublists with a word dog.

EX: `'(("Ben" 2 "dog")("Kath" 1 "cat")("Matt" 6 "dog"))`

should return `'(("Ben" 2 "dog")("Matt" 6 "dog"))`

This is what I attempted to do, but unfortunately it gives me an error.

```
(define (dog-only lst)
 (cond [(empty? lst) null ]
 [else (filter
 (map (equal? (car (cddr lst)) "dog")))] 
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `map` here, and that's not the correct way to use `filter`, you need to pass a `lambda` as a parameter. Also, you don't need a separate condition for handling the case when `lst` is empty. Try this:

```
(define lst '(("Ben" 2 "dog") ("Kath" 1 "cat") ("Matt" 6 "dog")))
(filter (lambda (e) (equal? (caddr e) "dog")) lst)
=> '(("Ben" 2 "dog") ("Matt" 6 "dog"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` takes a function, not an expression.

```
(define test '(("Ben" 2 "dog") ("Kath" 1 "cat") ("Matt" 6 "dog")))

(define (dog? e)
  (and (pair? e)
       (>= 3 (length e))
       (equal? (caddr e) "dog")))

(dog? (car test))  ; ==> #t
(dog? (cadr test)) ; ==> #f

(define (dogs animals)
  (filter dog? animals))

(dogs test) 
; ==> (("Ben" 2 "dog") ("Matt" 6 "dog"))
```